# Adding jquery to my ebay listing doubles up scrollbar

Tags: jquery

I have made two listings in ebay, one different from the another in only two words.

So, the problem is that in the first listing I have content that have its own scrollbar to scroll down and see the content, and that's what I want.

I tried to change only two words with my scripts and I came with the solution, there's only ONE scrollbar for the ebay page and it's the same scrollbar for the content(and that's what I want), so there wasn't two scrollbars.

Here's the first ebay listing(that I want its codes but I don't want two scrollbars in it):
http://www.ebay.com/itm/130927513021?ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1555.l2649
And here's the second ebay listing(that I don't want its code but I want the fact that there's only one scrollbar in it):

http://www.ebay.com/itm/130927893759?ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1555.l2649
The difference between the two codes:

The first one support `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`

The second support `.hide()` and `.show()`

The jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('current')) return;

        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('curre nt');

        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);

        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);

    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

As simple as that, I want the `.hide()` `.show()` but without the one added scrollbar(I want only one scrollbar for the content and the ebay page).

Comment: eBay is probably blocking all of that.

Comment: the example you gave is javascript

Comment: Nope, it's actually Jquery :|

Comment: don't understand your question, do you just simple want to focus your content on click 'li a' or some thing else. i have seen both pages but both have single scrollbar of page

Answer (score 1):

The unwanted scroll bars are going to be due to the IFRAME that eBay wraps all listing descriptions in.

When a listing is viewed some eBay Javascript is executed that sets the height of the IFRAME so that all of the description is visible. The required height is determined by what is visible in the listing's description as the script is ran. If there are any hidden elements that are larger than the IFRAME's height you will get scroll bars when the element is made visible.

I have created two examples that hopefully explain the issue. Both use the same HTML.

The first example starts with hidden elements which are not taken into account when the eBay Javascript sets the height of the IFRAME. Clicking any of the buttons will show the hidden elements. Since there is not enough room within the IFRAME you will get scroll bars.

The second example gets around the issue because the tallest element is initially visible  which ensures that the IFRAME will have enough height to display it. Clicking any of the buttons shouldn't result in scroll bars as all the elements are small enough to fit inside the IFRAME.

Example 1
http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=110117879641

Example 2
http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=110117879646

The Javascript that sets the height of the IFRAME is outside of your control as it has been generated by eBay. To ensure that no scroll bars appear you will have to design your listing's description so that the tallest element is initially visible and sets the height of the IFRAME so that it's tall enough to contain the other elements when they are made visible.

It has been mentioned before but eBay will not allow external Javascript in a listing's description so including JQuery could result in the listing been removed.